# Can not unbind the key End to "text end" on the Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

Any ideas?
Eclipse always asks me if "Text end" should be executed or "Line end" should be executed when I press the key END.
After I unbind the key bind of "Text end" on Preferences, Eclipse still asks me.

Version: Juno Release
Build id: 20120614-1722

Comment: same problem, except with Ctrl+E. must be a bug.

Comment: This is infuriating. Why is Eclipse hijacking my home and end keys? All text editors should have the same behavior in windows.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apparently there is a bug in Juno such that there appears to be a key conflict for the **HOME** and **END** keys even when the preferences don't indicate one. The restore defaults button does not correct the problem unless you first create a conflict manually, and then use the restore defaults button.

1. Go to Window->Preferences->General->Keys
2. Make "Line Start" and "Text Start" both use ONLY the **HOME** key, to create a conflict.
3. Make "Line End" and "Text End" both use ONLY the **END** key, to create a conflict.
4. Click Apply and then OK
5. Go again to Window->Preferences->General->Keys
6. Click "Restore Defaults"
7. Click Apply and then OK

This should put things back into sync, and fix the problem; at least it did for me on Juno for 32-bit Windows 7.

Comment: This worked for me but the issue seems to be fixed in the current version of Juno and the ADT version of Eclipse.

Comment: That works in my case as well for Eclipse Juno with Windows 7 64-bit. The same steps also work to fix "Shift+End" and "Shift+Home" combinations.

Comment: I also had this problem in Eclipse 4.3 Kepler 64 bit (20130614-0229) on Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Kepler version in Linux.

Close eclipse and open it solved my problem with home/end keys.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when I do not have time to mess with making the conflict and resetting in Kepler/CFEclipse, adding Shift still works to get End, Ctrl+End, Home and Ctrl+Home to select the text, and then remember to use the left arrow to unselect after Home and right arrow to unselect after End.